# SQL Selecting rows from two tables where values are different including nulls

Tags: sql, database, querying

I've read a few other posts but haven't been able to find my answer. I have two tables that I'm linking (A & B). What I'm trying to do is get all the rows where my column value is different.

I know I need an OUTER JOIN in order to retrieve these rows, but it isn't returning NULLS.

Here's my scenario: We (my company) are a third party business. We outsource work for our customers. So, when our outsourcer has a certain expense, I need to add that expense to my customers side of pay. Things fall through the cracks and we don't always remember to add these expenses to my customer pay (leading to us losing money bc we are reimbursing our outsourcer)

So, I'm building a report that will pull all the records from 2 tables (customer and outsourcer) which include payment details. I need to pull expense records from both tables only where the SUM of expenses (since there can be multiple expense records) don't match up. Meaning the values are different OR the outsourcer has an expense added but the customer doesn't  (meaning null values come into play)

Here's what I have but it won't return nulls. I'm thinking I might have to do sub queries but I'm not certain. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT c.jobNum, SUM(c.expenses) as cExp, SUM(o.expenses) as oExp 
FROM customer AS c
FULL JOIN outsourcer AS o
ON c.jobNum = o.jobNum
WHERE cExp <> oExp
GROUP BY c.jobNum
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You probably want `WHERE cExp is distinct from oExp`

Comment: When `FULL JOIN`, you usually put the conditions in the `ON` clause instead of in the `WHERE` clause. E.g. `ON c.jobNum = o.jobNum AND cExp <> oExp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
SELECT t.jobNum,t.cExp,t.oExp
FROM
    (SELECT c.jobNum, SUM(c.expenses) as cExp, SUM(o.expenses) as oExp
     FROM customer AS c
     FULL JOIN outsourcer AS o
     ON c.jobNum = o.jobNum
     GROUP BY c.jobNum
    )t
WHERE t.cExp <> t.oExp
```